# How to launch vscode installed on Windows 10 with winget from powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, winget

Trying out Windows 10 for first time. Installed winget onto my powershell, and then used winget to install vscode: `winget install vscode`. When I install vscode on a Mac/Linux, I get a command-line tool `code` that I like to use to launch vscode from my PWD: `code -n .`

But being new to Powershell and winget, I have no idea how to determine exactly what/where/how things got installed. In summary:

1. Is there a command-line tool like code installed by winget?
2. If not, how else might I launch vscode with a window on my PWD?

Comment: What happens when you use the moniker is `vscode`, as opposed to `code`? _(to see that you could use `winget search vscode`)_.

Comment: @compo Tried both `code` and `vscode`, neither are recognized.

Comment: Did you reboot after the installation, or at least try another PowerShell window, to ensure that the default location added to `%PATH%` is propagated to the new instance.

Comment: code should work fine. You should reboot just to be sure. Compo probably nailed it.

Comment: OK, rebooting solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK, after rebooting `code -n .` works as expected.